# XP-Pen Graphic Tablet is not working on blender

Tags: 3d-mouse

I have a graphic tablet which i always love to use to draw 2d drawings. it works perfectly on drawing programs. But when I use it on Blender the cursor jumps to the top left of the screen and it goes crazy,

Weird, since my tablet works just fine in another program.
I'm using XP-Pen graphic tablet. Sorry if it's hard to fix because it is not as famous as other tablets.
But do you happen to know how to fix it? Maybe it's problem with the driver or Blender setting.

[image: I've tried to tweak these 3 settings...]

I've tried to tweak these settings, but to no avail...

Comment: This has been asked several times and hasn't received any answer in Blender related cases https://blenderartists.org/t/xp-pen-graphics-tablet-is-not-working/700697 https://developer.blender.org/T63964 (on bug tracker it has awaiting reproduce status though). Seems to be specialized problem with those tablets. Try with [non-related to Blender](https://www.reddit.com/r/osugame/comments/6bt6x6/tablet_help_cursor_goes_to_top_left_of_screen/) solutions, *probably* some of them can work

Comment: Weird. Many people ask this on the internet too, when i was looking for the answer. I wonder do Blender Devs aware about this.

Comment: At least some of them do as the (presumably) bug is added to the bug tracker. Then it's the problem of reproducing it on their side which might be problematic if they don't own that specific hardware. You can add a comment to that case or even open new one which probably will end up closed as duplicate